# Is it possible to define an array in wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration

wp-config.php

```
$array = array("test1","test2");
define("TEST", $array);
```

testFile.php

```
$array = TEST;
```

Is this possible?  The above code merely sets $array to "TEST".  Or is there a way to retrieve values from wp-config.php by string i.e. something like:

```
$array_first_value = wp_get_config("array_first_value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array values can't be used with `define`. You can only use scalar (int, float, string, bool) or null.

Please see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: Beginning in PHP 7 arrays are an allowed value of the define function.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize an array for use in a constant and unserialize it later when you need it.

So, in wp-config.php, you could do the following:

```
$array = array( "testvalue1", "testvalue2" );
define( "TEST", serialize($array) );
```

And then in some other file:

```
$array = unserialize(TEST);
```

However, constant are not meant to hold arrays. So, you might want to rethink your need for a constant array.